# ¿Cómo verificar si existe un email en Firebase con Kotlin?

Tags: firebase, kotlin

Necesito comprobar si el email con el cual se registra el usuario ya existe en Firebase y mostrar un mensaje del error que me envié Firebase para poder identificarlo.

```
  fun authSignUp(){

    FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(editTextEmail.text.toString(),
                    editTextPassword.text.toString())
            .addOnCompleteListener {


                if (it.isSuccessful) {

                    val menuActivity = Intent(this, MenuActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(menuActivity)

                    val message = "Registro exitoso"
                    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()


                } else {

                    //Aqui deseo mostrar el mensaje del error 

                    
                }
            }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar una funciòn que verifique mediante una `REGEX` si el formato del email es valido o no:

```
private val emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+"

fun isValidEmail(email: String) : Boolean  {
      if (email.matches(emailPattern.toRegex())) {
         return true
      } else {
         return false
      }
   }
```

llamarìas de esta forma la funciòn:

```
          if(isValidEmail(editTextEmail.text.toString())){  //*Valido

                val menuActivity = Intent(this, MenuActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(menuActivity)

                val message = "Registro exitoso"
                Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()


            } else { //*NO Valido

                //Aqui deseo mostrar el mensaje del error 

                
            }
```